# Is there any MSBuild alternative?

Tags: c#-4.0

**I'm an under training student with so few experience of C#.
Our company is developing a solution using T4 templates (C# VS2010).
The generated files can't be compiled under MSBuild because it is VS dependent.
My task is to find a tool or a library or a .dll file or SDK or any thing that can replace VS in building time. Other wise I have to modify the generated code to be VS independent my selef, which I think is a diffucult task for me.
code samble:

```
Project GetProjectContainingT4File(DTE dte) {

// Find the .tt file's ProjectItem

ProjectItem projectItem = dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(Host.TemplateFile);

// If the .tt file is not opened, open it

if (projectItem.Document == null)

    projectItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode);

if (AlwaysKeepTemplateDirty) {

    // Mark the .tt file as unsaved. This way it will be saved and update itself next time the

    // project is built. Basically, it keeps marking itself as unsaved to make the next build work.

    // Note: this is certainly hacky, but is the best I could come up with so far.

    projectItem.Document.Saved = false;

}

return projectItem.ContainingProject;

}
```

I would appreciat your help.**

Comment: Can you expand on why it cannot be built using MSBuild? Even if there is something which MSBuild cannot build, you can use MSBuild to invoke Visual Studio to build it. You just use the Exec task and call devenv.exe.

Comment: they use a server to compile their project where VS is not installed.

Comment: You don't need VS installed to use msbuild. And you don't need VS to transform T4 templates either. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423(v=vs.100).aspx#buildserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction

> The generated files can't be compiled under MSBuild because it is VS dependent

seems very odd.  Why would you target the .NET environment but want your build environment to be MS independent?  Surely you at least need a C# compiler.

If you really want to use something besides MSBuild, there are a number of alternatives such as Mono's [Microsoft.Build](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build) or even [Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm).

Comment: Key phrase: "VS" dependent. *NOT* MS dependent. If you want to compile something on a CI server, for instance, you can't require a VS install on every single server. It's way too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild is basically a managed and highly extendable version of NMake and as such is not VS dependent! It IS however .NET dependent.

So you should be able to use MSBuild to orchestrate everything you need.

Even the C# compiler is part of the .NET runtime so you should even be able to build C# targets without incurring a VS dependency.